# Denys Fisher, of Spirograph fame, using a computer late 1976, early 1977

Tags: identify-this-computer, identify-this-peripheral

Denys Fisher, the creator of Spirograph, sold his company, bought an estate in Scotland and started working on his next creations, or at least so is narrated in a BBC's documentary, broadcast as part of "Tomorrow's World" in May 1977. I know because [a clip of the documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBvUahtCwqY) was posted on YouTube by the [BBC Archive](https://www.youtube.com/@BBCArchive) channel...

In the clip, we see [Mr. Fisher using a sort of personal computer](https://youtu.be/vBvUahtCwqY?t=184), that smells HP but I really don't know (in that years they made amazing stuff in UK!).
Also, just a bit later, we see a pen plotter drawing a jagged rendition of a complex pattern.

Do you know what computer, what pen plotter is he using?

Comment: It's perhaps worth recording that Denys is shown, in 1977, using the computer illustrated in the video clip on Youtube to recreate his Spirograph toy - which he had launched in the children's toy market in 1967. The computer program shown in the video clip is a precise re-creation of what the Spirograph toy did, which, as a toy, allowed a child to create very complex - if rather abstract - designs and patterns on paper, using any pen or pencil, with a small number of plastic moulded cut-outs supplied by the toy company, plus a pin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### TL;DR:

It's a HP 9825B desktop calculator and a HP 9872 flatbed plotter.

---

By the looks it can be either a HP 9825 desktop calculator (*1) introduced in 1976, or a 1978 HP9831 computer (*2).

[image]

*([HP 9825A Picture](https://www.hpmuseum.org/98xx/98253qm.jpg) taken from [Museum of HP Calculators](https://www.hpmuseum.org/))*

[image]

*([HP 9831B Picture](https://www.hpmuseum.net/images/9831A-35.jpg) taken from [HPmuseum.net](https://www.hpmuseum.net/))*

The fact that the video shows a calculator style keyboard does not help to distinguish between 9825 and 9831 as both were available with either full travel (xxxxA) or calculator style (xxxxB) keyboard.

**But** the 9831 was only available for a very short time in 1978, while the 9825 was produced and sold from 1976 until 1983. Thus, going by the recording year of 1977, this can only be a 9825B.

In turn the plotter seems to be a HP 9872, introduced in 1977:

[image]

*([HP 9872 Picture](http://www.hpmuseum.net/images/9872A-35.jpg) taken from [HPmuseum.net](https://www.hpmuseum.net/))*

***Looks like he got him the newest HP tech of 1977 in 1977 :)***

---

For more information see HP 9825 entries at

- [The Museum of HP Calculators](https://www.hpmuseum.org/hp9825.htm)
- [HPmuseum.net](http://hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=171)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_9800_series#Third_generation)

For the HP 9872 Plotter see

- HPmuseum.net [Entry](http://hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=79)
- Very detailed description in [HP Journal 09/1977](https://vtda.org/pubs/HP_Journal/HP_Journal_1977-09.pdf)

---

*1 - While HP classified the 9825 as top end calculators and follow up of the 9820, its handling is way more like a later personal computer, including a language called HPL, somewhere between the key-press recording of calculators and BASIC, which the 1972 [9830](https://www.hpmuseum.org/hp9830.htm) used.

*2 - The 9831 is essentially an 9825 with a BASIC/OS compatible to the 9830. This is possible due the whole 98xx series using the same base CPU derived from the [HP 2100 CPU line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_2100).

Comment: That sin(x)/x graph still looks good.

Comment: Did the plotter do those characters itself or was that the driving software? The latter would be usual but HP gear frequently has surprising ahead-of-their-time features.

Comment: @davidbak Character generation was self contained. The 9872 hat several fonts with 95 characters each (7 bit). Being vector fonts character strings could be printed in arbitrary size by setting the character cell width and height and of course plotted in any direction intended and 'beautified' with a variable slant. IIRC one could also add (a few) user defined characters, so logos or mathematical symbols could be transferred only once. The whole language was made optimized for short encoding.

Comment: @Raffzahn that may have been true in 1977.  I used an HP plotter around 1975 and I ended up creating my own vector font.

Comment: @MarkRansom Most likely a 7210A, which offered no higher functions than from/to coordinates to be plotted. It's calculator counterpart 9862A had already fonts ... or more correct, the interface included them as part of command interpreter :))

Comment: @Raffzahn an xref to the Hershey Fonts as described at e.g. https://hackaday.com/2021/03/30/hershey-fonts-not-chocolate-the-origin-of-vector-lettering/ might be of interest, it's a fairly useful discussion even if the origin of the fonts used by HP is unknown.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd nice find. That request puts me in peril - I believe I'm already infamous for writing way too long answers including way too much non essential information. So I rather leave that link to be found in the comments.

Comment: @Raffzahn I know we disagree on occasion, but I respect your scholarship and/or powers of recollection :-)

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd - HP drew their own fonts using a minimal number of lines. Allen Hershey, having access to one of the fastest computers in the world at the time, did not have that restriction

Comment: @scruss The cited article dates Hershey's work as 1967, by which time the computer he was using was a relic: thirteen years old, even if the output device was still interesting. I'm not sure about this, but HP might not have entered the plotter market at that time, and even if they had that does not imply that the fonts were hardcoded into the equipment or system software.

Comment: That's an expensive and time-consuming way to plot graphs. Wouldn't he had been better off with an Apple-II or something?

Comment: @OmarandLorraine What do you mean with time-consuming and in what way would an Apple II, which at that time of filming not even existed make his life more easy than a full figured BASIC programmable computer with all kinds of math libraries and a well adopted plotter being able to draw any schematics created?

Comment: This was 1977, when the Apple II existed. I think it would have been able to plot shapes to the screen more easily than loading paper and waiting for a plotter. I get the impression that HP stuff was expensive kit. But I take your point about the BASIC and the math libraries.

Comment: @OmarandLorraine The recording was aired in May 1977, the Apple II was first announced in April 1977 and first units delivered in June 1977. Further  with no other devices, no floppy (June 1978), no printer (Apr 1978). Only Integer BASIC and audio cassette. HP had fast digital cassette with floppy like operation. HGR resolution unable to show what he was doing. Most important,  who would spend month of additional time with unfit tools for inadequate results to save a few bucks? Hobbyist games do not add up in a business environment.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd - Hershey's report [Calligraphy for Computers](https://archive.org/details/hershey-calligraphy_for_computers) (1967) indicates that, while the system could run on NORC, it was also run on Dahlgren Lab's [IBM 7030 Stretch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_7030_Stretch) supercomputer. HP's first plotter, the 9125B single-pen flatbed (1968) for the 9100 calculator didn't appear to have text labelling ability at all. HPPLOT for the 72xx plotters (1969) added rudimentary labels, perhaps coded in the HPPLOT routine for the HP2000 computer

Answer (score 29):

My name is Duncan Fisher and I'm the youngest son of Denys Fisher. I remember dad's HP programmable calculator and plotter set up very well - can't shed any light on the specific model though.

What I can say is that he named the machine "Triggy" because it was good at trigonometry.

Also, he used the set-up to help with the design work on his next invention which was the toy "Cyclex" - launched in 1980.
Dad used a similar HP calculator right up until he retired in 1998!
At that time he had it controlling a Newing Hall CNC machine.

[image: Cyclex Toy]

Comment: Duncan, thanks for sharing!  I never heard of the Cyclex but I loved my Spirograph when I was a kid in the 70's.

Comment: Oh yeah, Cyclex! I remember I had one exactly like the one pictured!

Comment: Nice to have you in here, Duncan.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - it's great to read about your experiences with dad's toys. Thanks for welcoming me 

Answer (score 11):

The pen plotter appears to be an [HP 7221](http://www.hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=71) or [9872](http://www.hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=79). They look identical but differ in their interfacing: the 7221 is the RS-232 version and does not speak HP-GL; the 9872 uses HP-IB and HP-GL. If the computer is an advanced HP calculator, the plotter is probably the 9872.

This predates my use of pen plotters, which was in 1984-88, but it uses the same distinctive disposable pens as the HP devices I used. The [HP Computer Museum page on pen plotters](http://www.hpmuseum.net/exhibit.php?class=4&cat=24) lists quite a few models: I identified this one by the number and colours of the buttons on its control panel.

Comment: Close. HP 7221 was the serial version to be used for generic, non-HP computers. For 9815/20/25 calculators the 9872  featured the right interface and command language.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Updated, once I looked closer.

Comment: OOps my bad, the 9825 is using HP-IB. Conversion happened in the interface module plugged into the 9825.